# How are the different pips explained on Han's dice?

Tags: star-wars, props

In the original *Star Wars* trilogy, Han Solo's dice are seen with standard pips.  While there is no clear movie cell with these pips, there is this Decipher game card for their CCG:

[image]

Also, the dice were hyped in *The Force Awakens* in this *Vanity Fair* cover shot, also with standard pips:

[image]

In *The Last Jedi*, we see several closeups of the dice, now with "Canto Bight Casino" pips.  Here is the closeup of Leia's hand before they disappear:

[image]

And, to make matters worse, the story of the pips were not explained, but instead further muddied, when seen in *Solo*:

[image]

How is this continuation error explained?  Which pips are canonical?

Comment: the CCG game isn't canon design - it's basically fan art (as are most CCG art elements), not sure why there needs to be an inconsistency - in each film shot - we appear to only certain sides - not neccarisly the same sides

Comment: It's your position that the dice pips consist of a single dot pip, a three-dot pip, and these alien pips?

Comment: It would be my contention that the canon appareance of the dice do not contain real-world Earth type pips

Comment: Why then did they appear so in the Vanity Fair cover?

Comment: When Vanity Fair is a canon source, I'll think of an answer :D . Could be any number of reasons - design wasn't finalized, the well publicized change in director / staff could have affected the film scene concurrent to / post TLJ which wasn't completed at the time of the cover shoot. Also - that VF image that's posted looks odd to begin with and I have a gut reaction that the dice are photoshopped into the shot anyway - but it could just be an optical illusion caused by the typeface

Comment: The pips in IV, V, and VI will be retconned with the new design when The Super Duper Special Edition is released on MegaHD MindProjector format in 2040. In fact, it is actually the dice that shoot Greedo, but Lucas couldn't show that in previous versions because the pip designs weren't finalized.

Comment: hahah yes.  This is the answer, here.

Comment: The very short answer is that they simply retconned their appearance for TFA and then used the same design in Solo: A SW Story; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo%27s_dice - No explanation is given for their change in appearance.

Comment: @Tashus That's funny .. from what I heard the dice protected Han by deflecting Greedo's shot back at him so that Greedo ends up shooting himself.  And then Han is all "Oh .. no, what has happened to my poor friend Greedo?"  and then laments at how cruel and merciless the Galaxy is.

Answer (score 4):

These just appears to be retcons.  The original dice (if that is even what they were) were presumably no longer available.  (The original dice were probably not, after all, intended to important keepsakes of Han's.)  Lacking precise information about what they looked like, Disney just invented new ones with new decorations.

The dangling decorations in the Millennium Falcon cockpit in *A New Hope* are small and metallic, resembling dice.*  These have conventionally been interpreted as being actual cubical dice, based on the real-world practice of hanging pairs of dice (most commonly, giant plush dice) from the rear view mirrors of cars.  From the first time I noticed these ornaments, I thought of them as small metal dice—although they were much too small to make out whatever might be engraved on them while watching *A New Hope*, even in a theater.

However, it is possible to get a better view of them in some still images (where they are not swinging around at all).  Here are two, one a still from *Episode IV* and the other a behind-the-scenes photograph of the incomplete cockpit set.

[image: A fighter that size couldn't have gotten this deep into space on its own.]
[image: *Falcon* cockpit set]

Take a look at those dangling pieces up close.

[image: No dice!]

It is not even really clear whether they are cubes.  However, what there is no evidence of is engraved patters on the surfaces.  The streaks left by the light at continuous curves, with none of the additional specular reflections that you would expect to see along the edges of an etched pattern.

Why the Disney filmmakers redid the dice more than once is more of a puzzle, but the props may not have been coordinated during the making of the films; some of the work on them was going on simultaneously.

*The ornaments are not longer present in the cockpit by *The Empire Strikes Back*.  That can be seen in this image of the cockpit during shooting (although it is easy to verify just watching the film).

[image: *Empire Strikes Back* cockpit]

Comment: The reflection patterns in the closeup make me think they're cubes.  And you can see what appear to be three pips on the upper left face of the upper left object.